# how to solve runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference in astilectron in golang

Tags: go

## Hello, I am new to golang gui and I want to use astilectron. module to develop desktop applications.

I have installed it by the help of their online documentation but I am getting some error which I do not know how I can solve it.
whenever I run my go source file I get the following error.

```
astikit: starting worker...
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0x52fb73]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/asticode/go-astilectron.(*writer).write(0x0, {{0x599174, 0x11}, {0x5a22b3, 0x1}, 0x0, {0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0}, ...})
        C:/Users/eritt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/asticode/go-astilectron@v0.29.0/writer.go:39 +0x1b3
github.com/asticode/go-astilectron.synchronousEvent.func1()
        C:/Users/eritt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/asticode/go-astilectron@v0.29.0/helper.go:145 +0x41
github.com/asticode/go-astilectron.synchronousFunc({0x60ea0c, 0x114b61b0}, {0x60d668, 0x114b61e0}, 0x114afae8, {0x59eacc, 0x1c})
        C:/Users/eritt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/asticode/go-astilectron@v0.29.0/helper.go:133 +0x134
github.com/asticode/go-astilectron.synchronousEvent({0x60ea0c, 0x114b61b0}, {0x60d668, 0x114b61e0}, 0x0, {{0x599174, 0x11}, {0x5a22b3, 0x1}, 0x0, ...}, ...)
        C:/Users/eritt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/asticode/go-astilectron@v0.29.0/helper.go:144 +0xd8
github.com/asticode/go-astilectron.(*Window).Create(0x114b61e0)
        C:/Users/eritt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/asticode/go-astilectron@v0.29.0/window.go:380 +0x13a
main.main()
        C:/Users/eritt/development/golang/node/main.go:16 +0x137
exit status 2
```

this is the content of my go source file.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/asticode/go-astilectron"
)

func main() {
    var a, _ = astilectron.New(log.New(os.Stderr, "", 0), astilectron.Options{
        AppName: "My app",
    })

    w, _ := a.NewWindow("https://www.google.com", &astilectron.WindowOptions{})
    w.Create()

    defer a.Close()
    // Start astilectron
    a.Start()

    // Blocking pattern
    a.Wait()
}
```

could someone help me to fix this problem.
thank you.

I checked their github page, but I did not see any solution to the problem.
I have also read online articles but any of them is not talking about the problem.
I would be most grateful if someone could help me to fix this problem.

Comment: `NewWindow` call is probably returning an error. Check that.

Comment: Please I have tried that but to no avail.

Comment: So, is there an error? Based on the stack dump, I expect to see an error from NewWindow call.

Comment: Please could you give me the solution in  go codes.

Comment: `w, err:=a.NewWindow...` then check `if err!=nil { fmt.Println(err); return }` so you can see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

per the library doc on github [https://github.com/asticode/go-astilectron#create-a-window] looks like you missed out to supplying parameters for WindowOptions:

```
// Create a new window
var w, _ = a.NewWindow("http://127.0.0.1:4000", &astilectron.WindowOptions{
    Center: astikit.BoolPtr(true),
    Height: astikit.IntPtr(600),
    Width:  astikit.IntPtr(600),
})
w.Create()
```

it read below that:
`This is pretty straightforward except the astilectron.Ptr* methods so let me explain: GO doesn't do optional fields when json encoding unless you use pointers whereas Electron does handle optional fields. Therefore I added helper methods to convert int, bool and string into pointers and used pointers in structs sent to Electron.`

now it makes sense to me where the `nil pointer dereferenced` error is coming from. you need to explicitly supply pointers to each subfield of `astilectron.WindowOptions` object.

Comment: I have tested the code but still.

Comment: Please I am a visually impaired, could you suggest any other gui module which has screen reader support to me.

Comment: I have tried fyne but it does not have screen reader support.

Comment: sorry, I lack much experience there. I just dug though the docs of above lib based you your question. can you confirm if you did try populating Center, Height and Width fields of WindowOptions ?